# Visual Studio 2015 Xamarin deploy fail without error message

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to make a blank Android application with Xamarin platform in Visual Studio 2015. For that I have installed VS2015 with Xamarin and tried to make an application for Android. However, when I try to run it, it gives an error at deployment without showing any error message even if the build succeeded !

#### OUTPUT LOG DESCRIPTION:

[image]

Comment: The Ouput console shows Build FAILED. So can you post the full output log.

Comment: As @sJy suggested your logs would be useful here. Please obtain your verbose build output (https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1675684-where-can-i-find-my-version-information-and-logs-#verbose-build-output-logs) so we can take a closer look at what's causing the problem.

Comment: The stack trace is visible in your picture. BTW how is it giving you error without showing you the error message?

Comment: what do mean guys ?

Comment: I think its an issue with emulator. Have you tried on a real device??

Comment: no, never tried it on a real device , i tried xamarin android player and Android acceletrated _x86 emulator but nothing is working

Comment: @AlanClark , sJy what do you need to know about output log ?

Comment: @AymanAkk is your emulator working ??

Comment: yes @sJy it s working

Comment: @AymanAkk Do you get any feedback in your device logs? (https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1675684-where-can-i-find-my-version-information-and-logs-#debug-logs-for-xamarin-apps)

Comment: @AlanClark yes Alan , i ve uploaded the output log s screenshot up  , please take a look

Comment: Can you try `adb install [path to apk]` and see what that throws? Should be in bin\{Debug|Release}\*.apk

Comment: @AlanClark i ve got this error" Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?"

Comment: guys i found a solution but still i don t know why the error happend It's just a simple timing issue. Here are the steps to avoid this error:

Wait until the emulator 'lock screen' is showing.
Run the 'app' again 
Choose the running device (Should be the same emulator).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!